# Site Updates are Live!

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We updated the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We updated most of the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We have fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We've launching the shiny new user profile!

Visually it will "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. Once the updates are live, I'll update this post. Then if you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: @NormalHuman I use this site, and I've been waiting for this update for a while.

Comment: Thank you, Kurtis - this looks great!

Answer (score 1):

I did find one problem: the patent summary sidebar panel is missing its styles. For instance, see:

[What is the status of this patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/what-is-the-status-of-this-patent)

[image: Patent sidebar without styles]

This used to have a grey backdrop, and I think the field names and title were bold.

Comment: Great catch. This is a custom bit for this site that I missed. I'll pull the old styles and update it soon.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks again, Kurtis. This problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I found one other (minor) style issue, on the *Select Your Next Badge* screen:

[image: Select Next Badge]

The background of the container does not cover the entire contents of the dialog screen. I'm using Firefox 40.0.3 on Windows 2003, with no extensions enabled.

---

**Update:** My previous fix (now deleted) only masked the problem. The actual cause lies in the following rule (custom for Ask Patents, I think):

```
.subtabs a.youarehere, .filter a.youarehere {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

As you can see in the below image, the `Search for a Badge..` box does not have enough room to display inline with the "Available", "All", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze" links, because the `font-weight: 700` makes the text wider, which forces the input field down to the next line and forces the `all-badge-progress` div out of the container.

[image: Rule enabled]

Disabling this rule solves the problem:

[image: Rule disabled]

This rule applies to several other aspects of the site and noticeably alters the visual appearance if it is disabled site-wide.

I [requested a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268459/296888) to the default `all.css` in StackExchange Meta, to see if there is any agreement that this is a design issue with the new layout.

Comment: I'm looking into this one. I can't get it to reproduce, so I might have to do a little digging.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I found the cause of the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I have provided several possible solutions to this problem, and started a bounty for it on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268459/296888).